# How can I allow access to multiple users, using the same login, at the same time?

Tags: customization, users, login, membership

I am an entry level wordpress/website developer, learning how to do more and be of more value.
I'm currently working on my girlfriends website and we need it to be a membership site to protect premium content.

The content will be used in schools and be available to multiple users under one username and password at the same time.

Is there anything I need to do in order to allow this access? 
The users will not be able to edit anything on the site, just view premium content.

Comment: Have you tested if this is already the case? An incognito window or a second browser should be all your need to do so

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to do anything. You can test this by logging in from your own PC and also logging in from another PC or mobile device using the same, or a different Internet connection.

Comment: this is not a forum and greeting of any kind should not be part of questions nor answers. Usually no one bother to edit, but in this case it did take 50% of the answer and didn't add anything to it.

Comment: Do you know if there is a limit to the amount of people able to do this?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: No, there is no limit, just your servers resource/bandwidth limits.